# why Sendgrid does not send any confirmation email in my app in asp core 2.1?

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I started the "Account confirmation and password recovery in ASP.NET Core" topic in the Microsoft documents (Core 2.1), and wrote the entire application. But when I run the app, I don't receive any email. I made an account in the Sendgrid and set the key value there. Also, I debugged the app and watched the values, and all were correct. Even the username and password of the new user is saved in database with EmailConfirmation=false; I followed all instructions step by step, and all the debug email suggestions. But I can't see any confirmation email in my inbox (and spam, and other folders). Do you have any suggestion on how I can find my problem?

Here is the link address of the topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-2.1

then I wrote the following console app, but still nothing...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Mail;
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Example
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Execute().Wait();
            Console.Read();
        }

        static async Task Execute()
        {
            var client = new SendGridClient("my API Key I copied from sendgrid");
            var from = new EmailAddress("my yahoo email which is my email used in sendgrid account", "my yahoo");
            var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
            var to = new EmailAddress("my gmail ", "my gmail");
            var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
            var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";
            var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
            //Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you setup a minimal test in a console app or something and confirm you can send an email to yourself using your Sendgrid credentials?

Comment: I wrote the above console app, and copied the exact API Key that Sendgrid showed me once afrer creating api key. But, still it does not send any emails...

Answer (score 1):

I asked Sendgrid, and I was told that I cannot use my yahoo email (or gmail,...) as the sender email; this is part of the answer: "Yahoo observes an email security standard called DMARC. DMARC instructs email providers to reject messages where the From domain is a Yahoo domain, but the message originates from a non-approved domain server/service." So I need to use my own mail domain;